# ion-refresher doesn't hide after synchronization

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I just setup ion-refresher into my project and it loads data perfectly but it doesn't hide after completing the function

home.html

```
<ion-refresher slot="fixed" pullingIcon="arrow-dropdown"
      pullingText="Pull to refresh"
      refreshingSpinner="circles"
      refreshingText="Refreshing..." (ionRefresh)="doRefresh($event)">
    <ion-refresher-content></ion-refresher-content>
  </ion-refresher>
```

home.ts

```
  doRefresh(event) {
    console.log('Begin async operation');
    this.data.getTodayReservations().subscribe(
        reservations => {
            console.log(reservations);
            this.reservations = reservations;
        }, error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('Async operation has ended');
    }, 2000);
  }
```

Console:

```
Begin async operation
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
Async operation has ended
```

but after triggering the refresh event data loads up but refresh stays there on top like this image

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `event.complete();` in your doRefresh once the data is updated.

```
doRefresh(event) {
    console.log('Begin async operation');
    this.data.getTodayReservations().subscribe(
        reservations => {
            console.log(reservations);
            this.reservations = reservations;
            event.complete();//here
        }, error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('Async operation has ended');
    }, 2000);
  }
```

[API docs for Ionic 3](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/api/components/refresher/Refresher/)

Comment: when i add it i get this error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'complete' of undefined

Comment: ah sorry @S4L4H for **ionic 3** it is `event.complete()`. https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/api/components/refresher/Refresher/

Answer (score 1):

In ionic 4/5 use event.target.complete()